# /dev/mapper/lvm01-root.vol is 100% full

Tags: rhel

I have in a RHEL 7 the root partition full, but I don't understand what's wrong:

```
/dev/mapper/lvm01-root.vol   5.9G  5.9G  272K 100% /
```

Inodes is at 98%:

```
# df -i
Filesystem                           Inodes IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/lvm01-root.vol            70656 68716      1940   98% /
/dev/mapper/lvm01-tmp.vol           3072000    24   3071976    1% /tmp
/dev/vda1                            128016   347    127669    1% /boot
/dev/mapper/lvm01-var.vol           8192000  4805   8187195    1% /var
/dev/mapper/lvm01-opt.vol           3072000  5124   3066876    1% /opt
/dev/mapper/lvm01-home.vol          3072000  3964   3068036    1% /home


# vgs
  VG    #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree  
  lvm01   1   8   0 wz--n-  <41.51g  13.09g
  lvm02   1   9   0 wz--n- <200.00g 129.89g
```

Could someone help me to understand what's wrong and how to solve it?
Thank you, Lucas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the info you provide you have full root filesystem. What you can do is to extend it from the free space in VG (`lvm01`). The procedure is:

```
lvextend -L+2GB /dev/mapper/lvm01-root.vol

resize2fs /dev/mapper/lvm01-root.vol
```

First command extend root LV with 2GB (it's wise to be modest). The second command extend the filesystem. You may need to add `-f` to the second command to force the operation because its `/` filesystem.

If your root filesystem ix `XFS` you should use command

```
xfs_growfs /
```

to extend the filesystem.

To check which directory fill it execute

```
du -skx /*
```

and then dig in to bigger directories

Comment: RHEL 7 uses XFS as its default filesystem type instead of ext4, so the second command should probably be `xfs_growfs /` instead of `resize2fs`.

Comment: @telcoM, thank you, will add it to the answer.

Comment: Your answer covers the "how to fix it" part pretty well;  but since I had already written most of my answer to cover the "could someone help me understand" part, I decided to post my answer too. Hope you don't mind the competition :-)

Comment: @telcoM, the competition is always welcome. This is one good way to learn :)

Comment: Thank you, extending the LV is a way I already know, I would like to understand why the root is full and how to check what's file are filling the partition.

Comment: @LucasRey, mention this explicitly in your question.

Comment: @LucasRey, check my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Your root filesystem is very nearly full. You would be able to still store a lot of files to  `/tmp`, `/boot`, `/var`, `/opt` and/or `/home`, or to any sub-directories (and sub-subdirectories etc.) of those directories, but storing files anything else is likely to become problematic quite soon.

Why it is full? Well, depending on what choices you made during the installation of the OS, the root filesystem may have been created to fit just the software selected at the time of the installation (with some spare capacity). If you have installed more packages since then, you may have used up the space by installing more software.

Or if you have created a non-standard directory within the root filesystem, like `/projects`, then those files would be all occupying the root filesystem since you apparently didn't also mount a separate filesystem for such a directory (or hierarchy of directories).

Or you may have made some mistake that caused some large files to be created within the root filesystem.

To figure out what is filling the root filesystem, you could do something like this:

```
du -kx / | sort -rn | less
```

This will create a list of directories, and sort it by size. Obviously `/` will be at the top, since everything else is within it, but if there is a long multi-level directory path near the top of the listing, then that directory contains enough data to occupy a significant portion of the filesystem all by itself. So with this list, you can look at the biggest disk hogs first, to determine if they are legitimate or not.

With `rpm -qf <pathname>` you can query whether a specified file is part of any RPM package (and which package it comes from). If you find large files that don't belong to any package in some directory that is not supposed to be used for data files and you know you haven't installed any non-RPM-packaged software, you very likely have found files that have been created or moved there by mistake.

---

Fortunately, your root filesystem is on a Logical Volume Management (LVM) logical volume (LV), and the LVM volume group (VG) that contains the root filesystem has enough unallocated space to double or even triple your current root filesystem size without adding any new physical disks. **And you will be able to do that without rearranging partitions or even unmounting anything**, while the system is in use.

Note that RHEL 7 uses XFS-type filesystems by default. In RHEL 7, a XFS filesystem is easy to extend on-line (in fact, it can *only* be extended on-line), but it cannot be shrunk at all without backing up the contents and recreating the filesystem ("reformatting"). So you might not want to make your root filesystem needlessly large, as you will be able to extend it further at any time there is a need to do so.

Your filesystem is now about 6 GB in size. If you don't have any specific requirements in mind (e.g. new large software packages to install), then an about 20% reserve capacity on the root filesystem should give you a comfortable margin for regular use. So expanding the root filesystem to 8 GB right now might be a good idea. You can do it with a single command as root:

```
lvextend --resizefs -L 8G /dev/mapper/lvm01-root.vol
```

Or if you want to express it as "increase the current capacity by 2 GB", you can do it that way too:

```
lvextend --resizefs -L +2G /dev/mapper/lvm01-root.vol
```

The `--resizefs` was a new option to RHEL 7 and newer. On older systems, the standard method for LVM-based filesystem extension would have required two commands: first the `lvextend` command without the `--resizefs` option, and then use a filesystem-type-specific command (`xfs_growfs /` in case of extending a XFS root filesystem).

Comment: Thank you, extending the LV is a way I already know, I would like to understand why the root is full and how to check what's file are filling the partition.

Comment: Please see my edit.